# Re collapse Div And Reset Contact Form On Successful Submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onsubmit, contact-form

http://www.thecommonwealthmembers.com/

I designed a website, and used jQuery and CSS on the contact form at the bottom (click here to inquire). When a visitor successfully submits the information after clicking the submit form (only if successful) I want the Contact Form to reset itself and I want the div to collapse also. Any ideas?

Thank you,
Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, change your function like this:

```
function sendForm(form) {
    return PLX.Submit(form, {
        "preloader":"pr",
        "onFinish": function(response){
            alert(response);

            // collapse
            $('div.inquirecontent').slideToggle();

            // reset and set default value back
            $('div.inquirecontent form').trigger('reset');
        }  
    });
}
```

Comment: That is awesome, thank you very much, although when it resets the form, for some reason it erases the "Submit" text on the Submit button, and it's just blank. Any idea?

Comment: @Aaron Brewer: I'm sorry, I was thinking too complicated. Please see my edit.

Comment: Well thank you very much, my kind friend. I appreciate it very much so. Do you know where I should start to learn JavaScript? Or do you think I should skip JavaScript and learn jQuery? I don't know, know where to start? Thank you again.

Comment: @Aaron Brewer: I take the view that playing around for yourself is the best way of learning. You might want to mess around at http://jsfiddle.net, which is a simple environment to test HTML/CSS/JS in.